# How to distinguish version of compiler using preprocessor directive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c-preprocessor, roslyn

Is there a way to distinguish which version of compiler using preprocessor directives?

I'm having trouble with the new Roslyn compiler, which generates different code than the old compiler and I need to keep the code compatible for the team, which is using both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015.

Comment: The simple answer is "no, there isn't". If you can give more details about the exact situation you're facing, we may be able to give more helpful suggestions.

Comment: Indeed, why is the different code generation a problem? If the behavior is different, then we need to get a bug filed so we can fix it.

Comment: I'll try to gather the information about this and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "different code"? Is the IL different? And, if so, in what sense, and why does that matter?

Next, in what sense do you want to keep the code compatible. Isn't it enough to keep the version of the solution file at the one that VS 2013 generates?