# Can I make a preprocessor directive dependent on the C# version?

Tags: c#, constants, c#-6.0

Is it possible to define a compile time constant that would say if code is compiled by C# 5 or C# 6? For example:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(???LanguageVersion???)' != 'v6.0' ">
     NOT_RUNNING_ON_6
</DefineConstants>
```

Comment: I'll leave it to you to add the missing `>` on the first line

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32987410/109702

Comment: Check out [this answer to a similar question to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets?lq=1), utilizing build configurations.

Comment: It is similar to detecting .NET version, but from the answer bellow the difference is that it's not possible in a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constants defined in the project file are all set by MSBuild. Which doesn't know the compiler version. It also only delegates all those properties to the `Csc` task. Since the compiler doesn't set constants based on the version, you simply cannot do that.

You could use a custom build process wrapper that determines the compiler version and changes the project file accordingly, though.